# Textmate theme for Chromebook's Caret?

Tags: macos, themes, textmate, chromebook, caret

I am trying to get TextMate's like colors (dark variant) to Chromebook's Caret.

I did in Settings > User Preferences:

```
{
  //If you want to disable update checks at startup, change this
  "promptForUpdates": true,

  "defaultTheme": "textmate", //This should be any of the supported Ace themes
  ...
```

where I changed the defaultTheme to textmate but I still see the white-background theme.

How can you change the theme to TextMate successfully?

---

The default Json is

```
{
  "dark": false,
  "editor": {
    "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "styles": {
    //gutter
    ".ace_gutter": {
      "background": "#808",
      "color": "#CCC",
      "overflow": "hidden"
    },
    //print margin
    ".ace_print-margin": {
      "width": "1px",
      "background": "#e8e8e8"
    },
    //cursor
    ".ace_cursor": {
      "color": "black"
    },
    //whitespace markers
    ".ace_invisible": {
      "color": "rgb(191, 191, 191)"
    },
    //built-in constants
    ".ace_constant.ace_buildin": {
      "color": "rgb(88, 72, 246)"
    },
    //language constants
    ".ace_constant.ace_language": {
      "color": "rgb(88, 92, 246)"
    },
    //library constants
    ".ace_constant.ace_library": {
      "color": "rgb(6, 150, 14)"
    },
    //numeric constant
    ".ace_constant.ace_numeric": {
      "color": "rgb(0, 0, 205)"
    },
    //invalid code
    ".ace_invalid": {
      "background-color": "rgb(153, 0, 0)",
      "color": "white"
    },
    //folding markers
    ".ace_fold": {
    },
    //functions
    ".ace_support.ace_function": {
      "color": "rgb(60, 76, 114)"
    },
    //constants
    ".ace_support.ace_constant": {
      "color": "rgb(6, 150, 14)"
    },
    //types and classes
    ".ace_support.ace_type, .ace_support.ace_class, .ace_support.ace_other": {
      "color": "rgb(109, 121, 222)"
    },
    //paremeters
    ".ace_variable.ace_parameter": {
      "font-style": "italic",
      "color": "#FD971F"
    },
    //operators
    ".ace_keyword.ace_operator": {
      "color": "rgb(104, 118, 135)"
    },
    //comments
    ".ace_comment": {
      "color": "#236e24"
    },
    //doc comments
    ".ace_comment.ace_doc": {
      "color": "#236e24"
    },
    //doc comment tags
    ".ace_comment.ace_doc.ace_tag": {
      "color": "#236e24"
    },
    //variable
    ".ace_variable": {
      "color": "rgb(49, 132, 149)"
    },
    //xml-pe
    ".ace_xml-pe": {
      "color": "rgb(104, 104, 91)"
    },
    //named function
    ".ace_entity.ace_name.ace_function": {
      "color": "#0000A2"
    },
    //heading
    ".ace_heading": {
      "color": "rgb(12, 7, 255)"
    },
    //list
    ".ace_list": {
      "color": "rgb(185, 6, 144)"
    },
    //selection
    ".ace_marker-layer .ace_selection": {
      "background": "rgb(181, 213, 255)"
    },
    //step
    ".ace_marker-layer .ace_step": {
      "background": "rgb(252, 255, 0)"
    },
    //stack
    ".ace_marker-layer .ace_stack": {
      "background": "rgb(164, 229, 101)"
    },
    //bracket
    ".ace_marker-layer .ace_bracket": {
      "margin": "-1px 0 0 -1px",
      "border": "1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192)"
    },
    //active line
    ".ace_marker-layer .ace_active-line": {
      "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07)"
    },
    //active line (gutter)
    ".ace_gutter-active-line": {
      "background-color": "#404"
    },
    //selected word
    ".ace_marker-layer .ace_selected-word": {
      "background": "rgb(250, 250, 255)",
      "border": "1px solid rgb(200, 200, 250)"
    },
    //keywords
    ".ace_storage, .ace_keyword, .ace_meta.ace_tag": {
      "color": "rgb(147, 15, 128)"
    },
    //regex
    ".ace_string.ace_regex": {
      "color": "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
    },
    //string
    ".ace_string": {
      "color": "#1A1AA6"
    },
    //attribute name
    ".ace_entity.ace_other.ace_attribute-name": {
      "color": "#994409"
    }
  }
}
```

There must be TextMate Json somewhere. 
How can you get TextMate's theme to Caret for programmer?

Comment: Which TextMate theme are you trying to change too?

Comment: @user1155120 The basic dark theme.